How do I plot frequency distribution if I know the lower limit and upper limit of the weight of products?
I have a bunch of data which has the weight of different products with and without lid.



Location
Product
Date of manufacturing
Weight without lid
Weight with lid
Qty




US
Food
04/20/2024
3
5
2


US
Food
04/14/2024
72
79
1


US
Food
04/20/2024
79
84
2


US
Food
04/19/2024
82
86
3


US
Drinks
04/20/2024
69
76
1


US
Drinks
04/14/2024
8
13
5


US
Drinks
04/17/2024
51
56
3


US
Drinks
04/15/2024
4
6
4


Australia
Food
04/19/2024
13
14
2


Australia
Food
04/18/2024
8
17
5


Australia
Food
04/21/2024
89
97
2


Australia
Food
04/19/2024
5
13
4


Australia
Stationery
04/20/2024
63
67
4


Australia
Stationery
04/19/2024
74
76
6


Australia
Stationery
04/20/2024
72
80
5


Australia
Stationery
04/12/2024
32
34
3



What I'm trying to plot is the frequency distribution of the weights. On x-axis, I have weight ranging from 0 to 100 and y-axis is my frequency distribution. If, for example, I have a product whose weight with and without product is 72 and 79 respectively, the y-axis should be 1 for all weight on the x-axis between 72 and 79.
I'm expecting that I can plot a graph with data similar to below.



Weight
Distribution




80
7


81
2


82
5


83
5


84
5


85
3


86
3


87



88



89
2


90
2



Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Update #03: 10-05-2024
Given the new requirement to add the total quantity instead of counting the products, the new measure should be:
FrequencyDist_02 = 
VAR CurrentWeight = SELECTEDVALUE(FP_RANGE[Parameter])
VAR _filteredTable = FILTER(
    'Table',
    [Weight without lid] <= CurrentWeight &&
    [Weight with lid] >= CurrentWeight
)
VAR totalQuantity = SUMX(
    _filteredTable,
    [Quantity]
)

VAR _result = IF(ISEMPTY(_filteredTable), 0, totalQuantity)
RETURN _result


I had to create a new table, so it is now 'Table' instead of SampleTable.

Final result:


Update #02: 08-05-2024
After hearing the new requirements, you could work with a disconnected table that generates the values between 0 and 100, and an additional measure that iterates over each value between 0 and 100, filters the table to get all rows that have that current value between 'Weight without lid' and 'Weight with lid', and return the count of that.
Disconnected table:
FP_RANGE = GENERATESERIES(0, 100, 1)

Measure
FrequencyDist = 
VAR CurrentWeight = SELECTEDVALUE(FP_RANGE[Parameter])
VAR _filteredTable = FILTER(
    SampleTable,
    [Weight without lid] <= CurrentWeight &&
    [Weight with lid] >= CurrentWeight
)
VAR counter = IF(ISEMPTY(_filteredTable), 0, COUNTROWS(_filteredTable))
RETURN counter


The variable CurrentWeight will select the current selected value of the 0-100 series. In a table visual, it will just go row-by-row, so 0, 1, etc.
Afterwards, the table will be filtered whether that particular value is within a particular range of your products without lid and with lid values. I have added a screenshot below to get an idea of the value "13".

Note: if you slice later on by 'Product' or 'Location', the original 'SampleTable' will be different, and all calculations will be different.


Finally, it returns 0 if there are no rows, otherwise it returns the amount of rows.

Illustration of filtered table with value "13"

Final result:


Frequency distributions are not that easy in Power BI when you have gaps and the amount of sample data is small. Perhaps you could go for a third-party way using R or Python scripting that plots a density distribution (graph on the left) or histogram (graph on the right) for any specific product filter? When a particular product filter is selected, the graph gets recalculated.
This is my end result:

Setup:

Using the R visual, you need to include the values you would like to do calculations with. In this case, I have added the 'Weight with lid' and 'Weight without lid' columns.
Afterwards, you need to create the R code that would output a plot in R (which is then shown in Power BI). I have used the following code:
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset <- data.frame(Weight with lid, Weight without lid)
# dataset <- unique(dataset)

# Paste or type your script code here:
dataset <- unlist(dataset, use.names=FALSE)
plot(density(dataset)) # OR use histogram(dataset)


The unlist function flattens the dataframe into a single vector, making it easy to calculate a density graph or a histogram.
The plot(density(dataset)) line plots the density distribution of the data according to the R algorithm. The default output is, in my opinion, quite ugly, but it can be customised or you could use third-party packages like ggplot2 (again, read the documentation on how to use it in Power BI).

At the same time, it also fits your requirement to have a dynamic X-axis, but this is also customisable inside R.

Hello :-) , I am not well versed with R, neither do I have access to R right now. I do have a huge dataset, just that I've only shown a few lines as an example. I was kind of hoping PBi would have some ways to solve this.

Is it possible to clarify your question a bit more? Like could you show, based on your sample data, how you created the output table? It would make it easier to create a measure in PBI.

What I did in excel was, I created columns with values ranging from 0 to 100. For each of the rows, I added a formula to return 1 if the limits (weight with and without lid) falls within that particular column.  For example, for the first row in the table above, it will return 1 for columns with values 3,4 and 5 and 0 for columns with values 0-2 and 6-100. Then I summed up the total occurrences. I used this for plotting. But can't do it for huge datasets though. The excel file is huge even without it.

So it has to be on a row-by-row basis? If I look at your sample data, I see multiple rows that relate to the 'Food' category. Does this mean they have to be taken into account as well, or only one particular row?
I think I can get a working solution later this evening.

The categories doesn't really matter.. I'm looking into a row-by-row basis. My hope was that a filter can be added so if I want to see the distribution for a particular product or area, I can see that too. :-)

I have updated my original post with a new solution. I hope this is what you are looking for?

One last question, if there was a column called quantity in the original table, and if instead of counting the number of rows, I want to instead calculate the sum of quantities with the exact same condition as above, how do I modify the DAX code? :-)

I think a simple SUM or SUMX would work fine here. Can you give an example of how the quantity column would look like, with your sample data? Then I can modify the code.

Hello, I've modified the original post to include the quantity table and the new distribution table.. Hope that's sufficient. :-)

Updated my original post. Should work now :)
